# How to enable greedy @PathVariable for a particular @RequestMapping?

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I try to enable directory browsing in via a rest service. Its defined like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path="ls/{path:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> getDirectoryListing(@PathVariable("path") String path) throws IOException {
  // ...
}
```

However, the PathVariable `{path:.+}` introduces problems, if i use a directory-like definition. For example,

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/fileRepo/ls/dir/subdir
                                         \___ ___/
                                             V 
                                          {path:.+}
```

will result in

```
{
 "timestamp":1485690489272,
 "status":404,"error":"Not Found",
 "message":"No message available",
 "path":"/dataset/ls/processed/dir1/subdir"
 }
```

and have the debug messages on the console

```
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /files/ls/dir1/subdir
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/files/ls/dir1/subdir]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/files/ls/dir1/subdir] are [/**]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/files/ls/dir1/subdir] are {}
```

So. how to tell the RequestMappingHandlerMapping that `ls/{path:.+}` should all resolve to `getDirectoryListing`?

Comment: You can pass URL containing `/` only with `@RequestParam`, but not `@PathVariable`

Answer (score -1):

if you are sending dir/subdir in your path variable you need to escape the "/" character in your path variable.
You need to **encode** the path variable part of your url and **decode** the same at the request handler level.

Comment: nope, its not a encoding issue. url decoding is done by transparently by spring, apparently before the url is resolved in search for a request mapping